# How to dynamically update dropdown within a modulized shinyalert for each iteration of a for loop, when using html = TRUE?

Tags: r, shiny, module, shinyalert

I'm creating a shiny module, where I wish to display some pop-up messages to the user via shinyalerts and include dropdown menus via `htlm = TRUE` and `shinyWidgets::pickerInput`. For each shinyalert the options should be different and the alerts should appear right after each other when the user has selected the relevant option.
However, when running the shinyalerts within a for loop, only the first alert shows the drop-down, the following does not. Please have a look at the example below and screenshots. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Module UI:

```
mod_match_columns_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    shinyalert::useShinyalert(),
    actionButton(ns("run"), label = "Start!")
  )
}
```

Module server:

```
mod_match_columns_server <- function(input, output, session){
  ns <- session$ns
  
  options <- list(c("option_1","option_2"),
       c("option_3","option_4"))
  
  observeEvent(input$run, {
    for(col in 1:2){
      nms <- options[[i]]
      output[[paste0("dropdown",col)]] <- renderUI({
        shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
          inputId = ns(paste0("options",col)),
          label = "Options listed below", 
          choices = nms,
          selected = "",
          multiple = FALSE,
          options = shinyWidgets::pickerOptions(size = 15)
        )
      })
      shinyalert::shinyalert(
        title = "Pick an option!",
        html = TRUE,
        text = tagList(
          uiOutput(ns(paste0("dropdown", col)))
        ),
        inputId = ns(paste0("modal", col))
      )
    }
  })
}
```

Run module:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mod_match_columns_ui("match_columns_ui_1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(mod_match_columns_server, "match_columns_ui_1")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

First iteration:
[image: This is what I want]

Second iteration:
[image: Dropdown is not shown]

Why is the dropdown not shown in the second iteration?? Thanks

Comment: You have the `renderUI` defined inside `ObserveEvent`. That results in it being created with the same ID every time you click on the actionButton.  Then the same ID will not work second time onwards. Just create your `output[[... <- renderUI()` outside the observer.

Comment: You can show both `pickerInputs` in one shinyalert popup.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to extract the `output[[... <- renderUI()`part and run it in its own loop outside of the observer, when the module is created, however, this didn´t work. I still experience the same issue as mentioned above. In my real module, I render multiple outputs and of variable length, so it will not be an option to show the `pickerInputs`next to each other (as the list is potentially 10+)

Comment: It will come out in a list one below the other inside a popup.  Otherwise, as html=TRUE, the second shinyalert is not displaying the pickerInput.

Comment: Ok. Any other ideas? Can't get it to work. Would really appreciate if you can please submit a working example of your first idea, i.e. to extract the `renderUI` from `oberveEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

mod_match_columns_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    shinyalert::useShinyalert(),
    actionButton(ns("run"), label = "Start!")
  )
}

mod_match_columns_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      ns <- session$ns

      options <- list(c("option_1","option_2"),
                      c("option_3","option_4"))

      lapply(1:2, function(col){
        
        output[[paste0("dropdown",col)]] <- renderUI({
          shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
            inputId = ns(paste0("options",col)),
            label = paste("Options",col,"listed below"),
            choices = options[[col]],
            selected = "",
            multiple = FALSE,
            options = shinyWidgets::pickerOptions(size = 15)
          )
        })
        
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$run, {
 
        shinyalert::shinyalert(
          title = "Pick an option!",
          html = TRUE,
          text = tagList(
            lapply(1:2, function(i){uiOutput(ns(paste0("dropdown",i)))})
          )
          # callbackR = function(x) { message("Hello ", x) },
          # inputId = ns(paste0("modal"))
        )
          
      })
      
      observe({
        print(input$options1)
        print(input$options2)
        print(input$shinyalert)
      })

    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(
    mod_match_columns_ui("match_columns_ui_1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_match_columns_server("match_columns_ui_1")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time. However this is not what I want. In my real app, I’m planning on rendering multiple items in the shiny alert (including a variable table to help the user make the right choice in the dropdown menu), hence the content need to be displayed sequentially and not in the same popup alert. I will try to update the question to make it more clear when I’m in front of my pc next time. If you can make a working example of your first idea where you render the UI outside of the observer and display it sequentially afterwards in different shinyalerts I will accept it